# Eclipse Java, converting text from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In Eclipse I have a lot of Java code with scandinavian characters. When using encoding ISO-8859-1 everything looks fine. However, when encoding is set to UTF-8 I get a lot of strange symbols instead of the scandic characters. Due to environment reasons we need to use UTF-8.

Without manually changing the symbols back to scandinavian characters (cannot separate what character is under the symbol) is there a way to do this change in a "batch" or something? After the batch the scandic characters would be displayed correctly in UTF-8.

Comment: use a command-line tool, like `iconv`.

Comment: `native2ascii` is this what you want?

Comment: I don't know about native2ascii. All I want to do is convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution for Windows. UTFCast Express is a great little UI tool that supports conversion to UTF-8 by inputting one or more folders or individual sources. Highly recommended!